# JavaFX TableView scrolling issue

Tags: javafx, tableview, scrollbar

I am developing an application using JavaFX and I have created a table that contains some strings that are short and others that are very long. I added these lines:

```
Text text = new Text(getString());
text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(getTableColumn().widthProperty());
setText(null);
setGraphic(text);
```

in my cell class in order to view the entire contents of each string. This has caused the height of each row within my table to vary, with some rows being several pages long. It seems that the scroll bar works by scrolling past a certain number of rows at a time. This causes huge jumps in scroll speed when scrolling past the rows that contain long strings. Does anyone know of way to base the scroll speed on lines of text passed rather than table rows?